# get http raw (unparsed) response in http.client or python-requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm using Python to making HTTP requests. I need to raw HTTP response that looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 19 Jul 2004 16:18:20 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Sat, 10 Jul 2004 17:29:19 GMT
ETag: "1d0325-2470-40f0276f"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 9328
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<HTML>
<HEAD>
... the rest of the home page...
```

In python-requests I tried `response.raw`, but it's **NOT** raw HTTP response and it's just raw body.

Is there any way to achieve this goal without using `socket`?

P.S. I don't want to rebuild the raw response using parsed parts.

Comment: So what do you understand the 'raw response' to be? The header section? That's not available in raw form.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the format I've mentioned above.

Comment: So you just need the HTTP headers, and not the body, correct?

Comment: @MarkStewart No. I need to all of response in the mentioned format.

Comment: @JudaXovex: that's the status line, the headers, and the body. The status line and headers are not available in raw form.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm thinking **HTTP raw response** means: status-line + CRFL + headers CRLF + CRLF + body. Using `socket` I can achieve this, but it's need to handle ssl, compression and many other things. P.S. Some of HTTP servers are sending LF+CR! P.S. [RFC 2616: section 6](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)

Comment: @JudaXovex: servers that respond with `LFCR` instead of `CRLF` are broken, and the `http.client` / `urllib3` / `requests` stack is not able to parse their responses.

Comment: @JudaXovex: specifically, the `socket.readline()` call would return the line up to the `\s` (LF) linefeed, and the next line would start with the `\r` (CR)` character, which would cause it to be rejected as a header line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters _... stack is not able to parse their responses_. It's not true. Try it! `nc -lvc -p 1234 < http-response-with-only-lf.txt`

Comment: @JudaXovex: You seem to be talking about a response that uses only LF bytes and not CR. That’s not the same thing as having CR and LF bytes swapped.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right, only for headers. But I mean an abnormal request at all. (Really thanks for your time!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requests` doesn't *have* the status line and headers in raw form. You never need these in raw form, a RFC compliant response can be reconstructed trivially from the data you do have. `requests` uses the [`urllib3` library](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as its basis, and that library, in turn, uses the Python standard library [`http.client` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html). That module doesn't give you the raw data *either*.

Instead, the status line and headers are parsed directly into the constituent parts, in [`http.client.HTTPResponse._read_status()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5407aaf18b8d33d0a327991db366457ac6fead2d/Lib/http/client.py#L256-L287) and [`http.client.parse_headers()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5407aaf18b8d33d0a327991db366457ac6fead2d/Lib/http/client.py#L193-L214) (the latter delegating to the [`email.parser.Parser().parsestr()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.Parser.parsestr) to parse the headers into a [`http.client.HTTPMessage()` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpmessage-objects)). Only the results of these parse operations are used.

You could try to wrap the urllib3 connection object (via the [`get_connection()` hook](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.get_connection) implemented on a [`requests` transport adapter](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#transport-adapters)). Connection objects have a [`.connect()` method with supporting methods](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/c3157af5e3b272d3fbffef23ee6215a229f8c61f/src/urllib3/connection.py#L146-L184) that create socket objects, and if you were to wrap those in a file-like object and then peeked at the `.readline()` call data, you could capture and store the raw data there.

However, if you are debugging a broken HTTP server, I'd not bother with trying to bend `requests` and its stack to your will here. Just use `curl --include --raw <url>` on the command line instead (with perhaps `--verbose` added).

Another option would be to use the `http.client` library directly, make the connection, send your outgoing headers with [`HTTPConnection.request()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.request), then *not* use `getresponse()` but just read directly from `conn.sock`.

Comment: You say _You never need these in raw form_, but I need, because I need to analyze HTTP response format.

Comment: @JudaXovex: then `response` may not be the library for your needs. Or any other library based on `http.client`.

Comment: Is there any alternative library?

Comment: @JudaXovex: why not just use the [`curl` command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29402/most-straightforward-way-of-getting-a-raw-unparsed-https-response)?

Comment: There is too many requests and executing an external command is not too fast.

Comment: _but just read directly from conn.sock_. That's what I needed. Really thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`response.raw` does what you want

Answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56492298/1290627