# What does the 'raw' property mean in a python requests response?

Tags: python, python-requests

When using the python module `requests` to perform requests you can have the response in various formats (according to the [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/api/#requests.Response)):

- text: Content of the response, in unicode.
- content: Content of the response, in bytes.

But in some other examples ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests)) there is also a property named `raw`, which is not defined in the documentation.

So what does `raw` mean?

Answer (score 4):

It's documented [here](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content):

> In the rare case that you’d like to get the raw socket response from
>   the server, you can access r.raw. If you want to do this, make sure
>   you set `stream=True` in your initial request.

**Response.raw**

> Response.raw is a raw stream of bytes – it does not transform the
>   response content. If you **really** need access to the bytes as they were
>   returned, use `Response.raw`.

In **Response.content** the `gzip` and `deflate` transfer-encodings are automatically decoded for you ([source](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content)).

Answer (score 1):

File-like object representation of response (for advanced usage).
Use of `raw` requires that `stream=True` be set on the request.
This requirement does not apply for use internally to Requests.

https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/4983a9bde39c6320aa4f3e34e50dac6e263dab6f/requests/models.py#L609-L612

Answer (score 0):

`raw` is an attribute of `requests.Response` instances. It [does not seem to be documented in the obvious place](https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/api/#requests.Response), but [the source code says](https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/_modules/requests/models/#Response)

> File-like object representation of response (for advanced usage). Use of `raw` requires that `stream=True` be set on the request. This requirement does not apply for use internally to Requests.

Comment: Also, one of the answers in the linked questions links to https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raw, so presumably the anchor `#requests.Response.raw` existed at some point in time in that doc page.